# connect to oracle DB using TnsNames Alias

Tags: c#, database, oracle, connection-string, tnsnames

In my TnsNamesOra I have

```
TEST11.12.13.14 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 11.12.13.14)(PORT = 1234))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = TESTNAME)
    )
  )
```

If my connection string looks like this:

```
Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 11.12.13.14)(PORT = 1234)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = TEST))); User Id = admin; Password = admin ; DBA Privilege = SYSDBA ; Pooling = false; Connection Timeout = 30" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client
```

Everything works fine.

But I want to do something like this:

```
Data Source = TEST11.12.13.14; User Id = admin; Password = admin ; DBA Privilege = SYSDBA ; Pooling = false; Connection Timeout = 30" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client
```

But getting error

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: If you are using TCP what is the port number?  See connection strings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/  If you are using ODBC connection then make sure the connection is in control panel : Adminstrative tools : odbc data source (provider name).

Comment: You can see port number both in TnxNamesOra and first type connection.
As I understand when use TnxNamesOra alias I just need name so the rest is done by Tnx configuration. But somthing works wrong :(

Comment: providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client is getting the provider name from the ODBC data source and then getting connection server name from the source.

Comment: ODAC looks for your file at `ORACLE_HOME\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora` - is that where you put it? And you keep saying "Tnx" - is the x a typo? It should be an "s". https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/install112012-164342.html

Comment: typo, corrected